# All events on a page have stopped firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

At the height of despair here. I went away on holiday for 2 weeks with a working project almost at the point of release and I have come back to a problem.

Using Visual Studio 2010, C# for a .Net (3.5) Web project.

I have 2 forms (almost identical)

1. The document is created and the data stored in a database
2. The data is loaded from the database and is manipulated

Both forms contain a number of events (Code supplied below)

There are a number of events on the form that used to fire for the following objects

- Text Box tbPartNumber - OnTextChanged
- List Box lstbEmailSelectFrom - OnSelectedIndexChanged
- List Box lstbEmailSelected - OnSelectedIndexChanged

The Code behind for all events exists and I know have not been changed.

I know they fired as I checked them over and over and demonstrated the project to the team leader of the team involved.

I have come back into the office after a nice break and none of the breaks will fire. The second form still operates as intended.

I cannot remember making any changes before I went off so I am at a loss.

I tried adding a new object to the form this morning and it does not fire either

```
<asp:DropDownList ID = "ddlItemList"
                  runat                  = "server"
                  BorderStyle            = "None"
                  BorderColor            = "White"
                  Height                 = "99%"
                  Width                  = "48%"
                  AutoPostBack           = "true"
                  onselectedindexchanged = "ddlItemList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

with the code behind

```
protected void ddlItemList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(odbcString);
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

  string theLanguage = Session["Language"].ToString();

  if (Session["UserEmail"] == null)
    { // Session has timed out so get the user to log back in
    ........
    }
  else
    { // Still have the session data
      // Get the list of items for the item box

    try
      {
      ......
      }  // Try
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
     ......
     }  // Catch
    }
  }
```

Has anyone any Ideas ? I would appreciate any help I can get.

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
         AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeBehind="ConcessionDocument.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="XXXXXXXXQualityPortal.ConcessionDocument" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
             Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
             TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
             Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
             TagPrefix="asp" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head id="Head1" 
        runat="server">
    <title>
      Tokheim Quality Portal : Concession Document
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" 
          runat="server"
          defaultfocus="tbPartNumber" >
      <div>

        <center>
          <asp:Table ID = "tblConcession"
                     runat = "server"
                     width = "85%"
                     BorderWidth = "1"
                     GridLines="Both">


            <asp:TableRow>
              <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Left"
                             BackColor       = "#E6E0F8">
                <asp:Label ID    = "lblPartNumber"
                           runat = "server"
                           Text  = "Part Number">
                </asp:Label>
              </asp:TableCell>




              <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Left">

                <!-- **************************************************************** -->
                <!--                      Problem With this event                     -->
                <!-- **************************************************************** -->

                <asp:DropDownList ID                     = "ddlItemList"
                                  runat                  = "server"
                                  BorderStyle            = "None"
                                  BorderColor            = "White"
                                  Height                 = "99%"
                                  Width                  = "48%"
                                  AutoPostBack           = "true"
                                  onselectedindexchanged = "ddlItemList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                </asp:DropDownList>





                &nbsp;
                <asp:Textbox ID              = "tbPartNumber"
                             runat           = "server"
                             AutoPostBack    = "true"
                             OnTextChanged   = "tbPartNumber_TextChanged"
                             Height          = "99%"
                             Width           = "48%">
                </asp:Textbox>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID     = "lblPartDescription"
                           runat  = "server"
                           Text   = ""
                           Height = "99%">
                </asp:Label>

              </asp:TableCell>

              <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Left"
                             BackColor       = "#E6E0F8">
                <asp:Label ID    = "lblQuantity"
                           runat = "server"
                           Text  = "Quantity">
                </asp:Label>
              </asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Left">
                <asp:Textbox ID              = "tbQuantity"
                             BorderStyle     = "None"
                             BorderColor     = "White"
                             runat           = "server"
                             Height          = "99%"
                             Width           = "99%">
                </asp:Textbox>
              </asp:TableCell>

              <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Left"
                             BackColor="#E6E0F8">
                <asp:Label ID    = "lblItemrevision"
                           runat = "server"
                           Text  = "Item Revision">
                </asp:Label>
              </asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign = "Left">
                <asp:Textbox ID = "tbItemrevision"
                             BorderStyle = "None"
                             BorderColor = "White"
                             runat = "server"
                             Height = "99%"
                             Width = "99%">
                </asp:Textbox>
              </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>



            <asp:TableRow>
              <asp:tableCell ColumnSpan = "6"
                             HorizontalAlign="Center" >

                <asp:Table ID = "tblEmailBoxes"
                           runat = "server"
                           width = "99%"
                           BorderWidth = "0"
                           GridLines="None">
                  <asp:TableRow>

                    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                   width = "45%">
                      <asp:Label ID    = "lblSelectEmailAddress"
                                 runat = "server"
                                 Font-Bold = "true"
                                 Text  = "Select An Email Address For The Distribution List">
                      </asp:Label>

                  <!-- **************************************************************** -->
                      <!--                      Problem With this event                     -->
                      <!-- **************************************************************** -->

                      <asp:ListBox ID = "lstbEmailSelectFrom"
                                   runat = "server"
                                   AutoPostBack = "true"
                                   OnSelectedIndexChanged="MoveToListBox2"
                                   SelectionMode = "Multiple"
                                   width = "99%">
                      </asp:ListBox>



                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                   width = "10%">
                      <asp:Button ID = "btnMoveRight"
                                  runat = "Server"
                                  Text = ">" 
                                  visible = "false"
                                  onclick="btnMoveRight_Click" />
                      <br />
                      <asp:Button ID = "btnMoveLeft"
                                  visible = "false"
                                  runat = "Server"
                                  Text = "<" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                   width = "45%">
                      <asp:Label ID    = "lblEmailAddressesSelected"
                                 runat = "server"
                                 Font-Bold = "true"
                                 Text  = "Email Addresses Selected For The Distribution List">
                      </asp:Label>

                  <!-- **************************************************************** -->
                      <!--                      Problem With this event                     -->
                      <!-- **************************************************************** -->

                      <asp:ListBox ID = "lstbEmailSelected"
                                   runat = "server"
                                   AutoPostBack = "true"
                                   OnSelectedIndexChanged="MoveToListBox1"
                                   SelectionMode = "Multiple"
                                   width = "99%">
                      </asp:ListBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                   </asp:TableRow>

                  <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                   width = "45%"
                                   ColumnSpan = "3" >
                      <center>
                        <asp:Button ID = "btnSubmit"
                                    runat = "server" 
                                    text = "Submit"
                                    OnClick="btnSubmit_Clicked"/>

                      </center>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                   </asp:TableRow>


                  </asp:Table>


              </asp:tableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
          </asp:Table>        

          <center>

                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" 
                                runat="server" 
                                Height="35px" 
                                Width="406px" />
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnFileLoadPostback" 
                            runat="server" 
                            Text="Load File" 
                            onclick="btnFileLoadPostback_Click" Height="35px" Width="131px" />

              <br />
              <asp:Image id       = "Image7"
                         ImageUrl = "~/Images/indicator3.png"
                         Style    = "display:None"
                         runat    = "server" />

          </center>



          <asp:Label ID    = "theFileList"
                     runat = "server"
                     Text  = ""
                     visible = "false">
          </asp:Label>

        </center>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean and build?

Comment: What happens when you revert to an older build?

Comment: *I cannot remember making any changes before I went off* Does this mean you're not using any sort of source control on your code?  I know this doesn't help in your current situation, but having source control in place would have proved it for you

Comment: Source control would have been useful. A good pointer for next time

Comment: Hi All

Thanks for your fast and helpful responses. I have tried

1. To Clean the project and rebuild it. No change.
2. Added the targetFramework to the Compilation tag. No Change.
3. Deleted the individual objects from the form and re-added them. No Change.
4. Deleted the form from the project and recreated it. No Change.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem.

I had added a registration to close a window and it appears that this has disabled all events on the form. If I remove it all works (apart from the window not closing)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  { 
  if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();"); 
    }
  }
```

Removed the registration and all works well

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Clean the solution and rebuild.
2. Check form view is refereeing to desired code behind cs file.

Comment: Appeared to be all over the place 8-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe change a namespace or something in the header of the ASPX page that is resulting in things not wiring up correctly? Incorrect version of DLL for the deployed page? As above, a clean and redeploy is the best place to start.

Comment: No. I have not changed the Namespace

Answer (score 0):

add inside

`<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="3.5"/>
</system.web>`

and Rebuild project hope it will solve your problem

Comment: <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="3.5"/> results in Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' message